# Passing multiple variables to the next HTML page using Flask (Specifically "Value" and "Selected", not just "Selected")

Tags: python, html, flask

I am using **Flask** to create an **HTML** form (dropdown menu), where the values are being populated from a list values (which is output from a python function). The variable in the python app.py code is "*two_dimensional_list*" The sample values are:
*[['001','Source1'],['342','Source2'],['968','Source5']]*
(essentially the data is "IDs" and "Data Source Names"). The app.py code looks like this:

## app.py

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    #drop down list  (call Paxata to get a list of projects)
    two_dimensional_list = PaxMatch.get_datasource_configs(authorization_token,paxata_url)
    return render_template('index.html', datasources1=two_dimensional_list, datasources2=two_dimensional_list)
```

## index.html

```
  <select name= datasource1 method="POST" action="/">
    {% for datasource1 in datasources1 %}
    <option value= "{{datasource1[0]}}">{{datasource1[1]}</option>"
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
```

This is working fine, and the HTML page is being built correctly, ie:

```
<option value="001">Data Source 1</option>"
<option value="342">Data Source 2</option>"
<option value="968">Data Source 5</option>"
```

The challenge I am facing is that when I click the submit button, the only thing that is being passed to "Step2.html" (the next page) is the "value" (which is the "ID") and not the "Description". I need both.

It's an embarrassingly simple problem to solve I am sure, but can't seem to work out how to do it without calling my python function again which is incredibly inefficient.

Appreciate your help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible workaround.

Define your two-dimensional list variable outside of the function:

```
two_dimensional_list = [['001','Source1'],['342','Source2'],['968','Source5']]
```

Define your `render_template()` function:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', two_dimensional_list=two_dimensional_list)
```

Setup your form template:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('data') }}">
  <select name="datasource" method="POST" action="/post">
    {% for datasource1 in two_dimensional_list %}
    <option value= "{{datasource1[0]}}">{{datasource1[1]}}</option>"
    {% endfor %}
  </select>  
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Last but not least:

1. Get the selected *ID* value with `request.form.get`
2. Access the *Description* value with `description_value(select)`
3. Print out the result

```
@app.route('/data', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def data():
    id_value = request.form.get('datasource')
    def description_value(select):
        for data in two_dimensional_list:
            if data[0] == select:
                return data[1]
    return description_value(id_value)
```

Comment: Thanks @Gabriel H. but I am still a bit confused. The problem I have with the solution you have provided above is that the two_dimensional_list (which is now a "dictionary" based on the previous suggestion) is not a global variable. Are you suggesting that I make this a global variable?

Comment: I defined it globally... Seemed to be the only way to not have to call the function a second time. Thanks!

Comment: An update... I decided (for now) to use cookies to store the different variables I am going to need... Please tell me why that is a good/bad idea! Thanks!

Comment: Could be unsafe depending on the data. Consider storing it in sessions! Or add a caching layer in the Python code that keeps the data around after it has been fetched.

Comment: Thanks again @gerwin I'll give sessions a try.

Answer (score 0):

That's just how the select input works so you have to call the function again. You can make it more efficient and more semantic by using a dictionary with the ID as key and descriptions as values. :)

Comment: Thanks @gerwin. Have changed the code to use a dict rather than a list (thanks for the suggestion), but surely there has to be a way for me to avoid calling that function again? (It can take up to 30 seconds to return all the data). Once I have it, is there not a way that I can possibly even pass the whole dict to the next page perhaps?